# Websocket to handle ByteString and String in Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.5

Am new to Play Framework and Scala. I was trying to write file upload using websockets in play. I figured out that it can be done using `ByteString`. But the problem that am facing is that I am not able to keep the response messages as `String`.

```
def upload = WebSocket.accept[ByteString, String] { request =>
  ActorFlow.actorRef(out => UploadActor.props(out))
}
```

The exception am getting is as follows,

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[could not find implicit value for parameter transformer: play.api.mvc.WebSocket.MessageFlowTransformer[akka.util.ByteString,String]]
  at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
  at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
  at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
  at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
  at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
  at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
  at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
  at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

The Actor to handle the websocket is as follows,

```
class UploadActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor{
  out ! "Hello"

  def receive = {
    case msg: ByteString => {
      val p = new PrintWriter(new File("/tmp/newFile.mp4"))
      p.print(msg.asByteBuffer)
      p.flush()
      out ! "file received"
    }
    case msg: String => out ! ("Got it "+ msg)
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Playframework WebSocket support relies on Akka Streams and therefore represents a generic WebSocket message flow as a `Flow` of type `Message` to `Message`. Any other combination of input and output parameters needs to be provided implicitly as a `MessageFlowTransformer[In, Out]`.

Now, a few transformers are provided by Playframework - e.g. `MessageFlowTransformer[String, String]`, `MessageFlowTransformer[ByteString, ByteString]`, etc. For a complete list check out the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/WebSocket.scala#L97).

If you want `ByteString` to `String` you'd need to provide your own transformer in scope. It would look like the following:

```
implicit val byteStringToStringMessageFlowTransformer: MessageFlowTransformer[ByteString, String] = {
      new MessageFlowTransformer[ByteString, String] {
        def transform(flow: Flow[ByteString, String, _]) = {
          AkkaStreams.bypassWith[Message, ByteString, Message](Flow[Message] collect {
            case BinaryMessage(data) => Left(data)
            case TextMessage(_) =>
              Right(CloseMessage(
                Some(CloseCodes.Unacceptable),
                "This WebSocket only supports binary frames"))
          })(flow map TextMessage.apply)
        }
      }
    }
```

More info in the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets).

Comment: I have placed the given code in the controller, but it's still the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Play 2.5 Scala WebSockets have actually gone through refactoring:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/StreamsMigration25#Migrating-Scala-WebSockets

You can now use `play.api.http.websocket.Message` to send and receive websocket frames of various types:

```
WebSocket.accept[Message, Message] { request =>
  ActorFlow.actorRef { out =>
    WebSocketActor.props(out)
  }
}
```

See [the sealed trait Message](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/scala/play/api/http/websocket/Message.html) for `BinaryMessage`, `TextMessage`, etc.